# Error when converting MATLAB's datenum to Python's datetime

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have to convert a MATLAB's datenum to Python's `datetime`.
The following code is as below:

```
import datetime
matlab_datenum = 63650571169.50261
python_datetime = datetime.date.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + \
    datetime.timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1) - datetime.timedelta(days=366)
print(matlab_datenum)
```

The above code generates this error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

How, can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `63650571169.50261` this number seems to big to be a MATLAB datenum first of all, MATLAB datenums are number of days from January 0, 0000, this number is equivalent to 174385126 years. Is this the time when aliens are going to make contact ? The overflow issue could be related to this

Comment: 63650571169.50261 is a datenum that represents a date plus a time for example 2010-11-04 00:03:50.209589. so, how can i obtain a date plus a time ?

Answer (score 1):

Your datenum is in seconds from the matlab epoch.  To convert to a `datetime` you need to offset that number of seconds to a `datetime` that python understands.  This function uses the Unix epoch as that reference.

**Code:**

```
import datetime as dt

# define some constants
epoch = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
matlab_to_epoch_days = 719529  # days from 1-1-0000 to 1-1-1970
matlab_to_epoch_seconds = matlab_to_epoch_days * 24 * 60 * 60

def matlab_to_datetime(matlab_date_num_seconds):
    # get number of seconds from epoch
    from_epoch = matlab_date_num_seconds - matlab_to_epoch_seconds

    # convert to python datetime
    return epoch + dt.timedelta(seconds=from_epoch)
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(matlab_to_datetime(63650571169.50261))
```

**Results:**

```
2017-01-01 10:12:49.502609
```